# Issues with running "Diggles, the Myth of Fenris" ("Wiggles") on Windows 7

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, diggles-myth-of-fenris

Has anyone gotten *Diggles, the Myth of Fenris* (original name: *Wiggles*) to run on Windows 7 -- with sound? It sometimes works on my laptop but it's too slow, and on my main machine, the sound isn't working. This seems to be a well-known problem, does anyone know what I can do? Or know a good virtual machine with graphics support?

Comment: @Mana why did you remove the wiggles tag? That's the name of the game

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I replaced it with the diggles tag, as per [this meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/add-tag-for-diggles-the-myth-of-fenris). Unfortunately, since this was the only question about Diggles, the tag expired, and so my edit seems to simply remove wiggles as opposed to replacing it with a different tag.

Comment: @Mana thanks, I see. inconveniently that is not visible in the revision history, while the non-existent [tag:wiggles] is still there.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler So I noticed! Kind of weird.

Comment: @Mana I consider it [a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107062/revision-log-not-showing-tags-added-that-no-longer-exist), or at least very inconsistent as mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run the game in compatibility mode? It is often the only way to solve issues with older games.

Comment: doesn't work :(